# how i can reject the loading completly if any single record is bad through sql*loader in oracle

Tags: oracle

How can I completely reject the loading if any single record is bad.  sql*loader in oracle.options(errors=0) is not helpful. I want a complete rollback if there are any bad records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL*Loader doesn't work that way. Load into a separate table, and truncate the table if things didn't work out.

Comment: Hi shannon, thanks for your assistance, so not possible by using the target table only instead of using like temp table.